# Unable to send Password from mvn command line which contains $ sing

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, command-line

I am Trying to run Selenium Script though Maven command line using below command

mvn clean verify -DPassword="Somee$#pa$w9$E"

and in below line i am fetching that value

loginPage.enterPassword(System.getProperty("Password"));

The charters after sing $ are not passed The value read by System.getProperty is = Somee0pa

Someone please let me know what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Got this on working has i am sending password in double codes when i run below command it works fine.

mvn clean verify -DPassword='Somee$#pa$w9$E'

Answer (score 0):

Got this on working has i am sending password in double codes when i run below command it works fine. mvn clean verify -DPassword='Somee$#pa$w9$E'